# How do I pass an object into a hidden form in php?

Tags: php, json, object, serialization

I have an object called $todovalues and a form. I need to pass the entirety of the todovalues object through the form.

My form looks like -

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input class="todobuttons" type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
<input class="todobuttons" type="submit" name="edit" value="edit">
<input type="hidden" name="post_item_info"
value="<?php echo serialize($todovalues); ?>">
</form>
```

I can access the values in $todovalues by using something like echo $todovalues->text.

I have tried to use serialize, json_encode, and a mixture of both. However, when I try to access the post value it is always empty.

Is there a way to take my object and add it to the hidden input without having to create individual hidden inputs for each piece of the object that I want?

```
json_encode($todovalues);
json_encode(serialize($todovalues));
serialize($todovalues);
```

None of the above have been functional yet. Is there no simplified method to pass the whole of an object without iterating through the object first? It just seems like a waste of space to have to create hidden inputs for each item in the object.

EDIT -

When I use json_encode() I see the following so I know it SHOULD exist -

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_item_info" value="{" id_auto":"3","id":"1","id_list":"1","completed":"0","incident_notes":"apple"}"="">
```

Comment: I would use `json_encode()`. When you view the source of the page is that value populated? If not there is another issue.

Comment: You should probably create a method within your object to return all relevant values as an array that you can then process with json_encode. Showing us the structure of the class would help too.

Keep in mind that static members are not serialized.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Updated with the contents of the json_encode

Comment: The JSON looks a little incomplete as you put it there, but it should be in the `$_POST` array when you send it. Do a `print_` or `var_dump` of the `$_POST` array.

Comment: @JayBlanchard There are double quotes inside the value. So what it is doing is closing the value right after the {. I think I need to escape the double quotes.

Comment: Either that or change to single quotes `value='{" id_auto":"3",...}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, you try to encode object. Try encode an array:

```
json_encode((array) $todovalues);
```

**UPD.** Or, it can happens because your html looks like this:

```
<input value="{"id":3....}"> (a lot of ")
```

You can try `base64_encode()`

Comment: Just saw that. I switched to single quotes but base64 is probably a better idea.

Comment: I added the base64_encode and now it works great. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

The json_encode was breaking due to the fact that I created the input using double quotes.

The system saw -

> value="{" stuffGoesHere "

I switched to single quotes -

> value=' {"stuffGoesHere" '

It works perfect now.